# Faster way to tell if a sprite is near another sprite?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

When one of my sprites is being dragged (moved around), I'm cycling through other sprites on the canvas, checking whether they are in range, and if they are, I set a background glow on them.  Here is how I'm doing it now:

```
//Sprite is made somewhere else
public var circle:Sprite;

//Array of 25 sprites
public var sprites:Array;

public function init():void {
    circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrag);
}

private function startDrag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, glowNearbySprites);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrag);

    circle.startDrag();
}

private function stopDrag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, glowNearbySprites);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrag);

    circle.stopDrag();
}

private function glowNearbySprites(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
        var tSprite = sprites.getItemAt(i) as Sprite;
        if (Math.abs(tSprite.x - circle.x) < 30 && 
                   Math.abs(tSprite.y - circle.y) < 30) { 
            tSprite.filters = [new GlowFilter(0xFFFFFF)];
        }
        else {
            tSprite.filters = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I'm cycling through each sprite every time a MOUSE_MOVE event is triggered.  This works fine, but the lag when dragging the sprite around is pretty noticeable.  Is there a way to do this that is more efficient, with no or less lag?

Comment: I'm not much of a game dev, but I guess you'd rather listen on ENTER_FRAME than on MOUSE_MOVE. I fail to see how this is related to Flex though.

Comment: There is a world of things you can change to make this faster. Like RIAstar said do it in enter frame event. Don't use getItemAt. Turn sprites array into a vector. Use a foreach loop and let the loop handle the var creation and type casting. There are more just nothing easy coming to mind atm.

Comment: Would it be at all practical to have a transparent object that's part of either you're dragged object or the targets that's the size of the "zone" and just hit test on that?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I had thought of that, but I also register click listeners on the other sprites, so increasing the target size would also increase the click zone.

Comment: @The_asMan, thanks those are all performance enhancements i'll change, except maybe the enter frame event.  I want to have the glow triggered when the sprite is near, not just on top of.

Comment: Using ENTER_FRAME as opposed to mouse move isn't going to impact your ability to determine if something is near rather than on top of it's simply going to reduce the amount of times the function is called to 24 times per second instead of 100s of times per seconds, multiple mouse move events will be dispatched within a single frame refresh so you're running this method more often than necessary.  You only care to check if you're at the point of updating the display otherwise they're pointless calculations.

Comment: Make the transparent area not mouse enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, depending on the size of the amount of sprites you have, it may be trivial.  However, if you're dealing with over 1k sprites -- use a data structure to help you reduce the amount of checks.  Look at this [QuadTree Demo](http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=202)

Basically you have to create indexes for all the sprites, so that you're not checking against ALL of them.  Since your threshold is 30, when a sprite moves, you could place it into a row/column index of int(x / 30), int(y / 30).  Then you can check just the sprites that exist in 9 columns around the row/column index of the mouse position.

While this would seem more cumbersome, it actually it way more efficient if you have more items -- the number of checks stays consistent even as you add more sprites.  With this method I'm assuming you could run 10k sprites without any hiccup.

Other performance optimizations would be:

- use an vector/array of sprites rather than getChildAt
- preincrement i (++i)
- store a static single instance glowfilter, so it's only one array, rather creating a separate filter for all the sprites.
- GlowFilter is pretty CPU intensive.  Might make sense to draw all the sprites together in one shot, and then apply GlowFilter once to it -- (this of course depends on how you have things set up -- might even be more cumbersome to blit your own bitmap).
- Make your variable declaration var sprite:Sprite = ....  If you're not hard typing it, it has to do the "filters" variable lookup by string, and not by the much faster getlex opcode.

Comment: This data structure technique seems very interesting / viable.  Also, including the other performance optimizations has already yielded better results,  thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to compile the suggestions by others into a solution based on your original code, so far I've created the GlowFilter only once and re-used, secondly I've changed the loop to use a for each instead of the iterant based loop, third I've updated to use ENTER_FRAME event instead of MOUSE_MOVE.  The only thing I've left out that's been suggested so far that I see is using a Vector, my knowledge there is pretty much nil so I'm not going to suggest it or attempt until I do some self education. **Another Edit**

Just changed the declaration of sprites to type Vector no code here for how it's populated but article below says you can basically treat like an Array as it has all the same method implemented but has a couple of caveats you should be aware of, namely that you cannot have empty spots in a Vector and so if that is a possibility you have to declare it with a size.  Given it knows the type of the object this probably gets a performance gain from being able to compute the exact position of any element in the array in constant time (sizeOfObject*index + baseOffset = offset of item).  The exact performance implications aren't entirely clear but it would seem this will always result in at least as good as Array times if not better.
http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/19/using-vectors-in-actionscript-3-and-flash-player-10/

```
//Array of 25 sprites
public var sprites:Vector.<Sprite>;
private var theGlowFilterArray:Array;
public function init():void
{
    theGlowFilterArray = [new GlowFilter(0xFFFFFF)];
    circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrag);
}

private function startDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrag);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, glowNearbySprites);

    circle.startDrag();
}

private function stopDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrag);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, glowNearbySprites);

    circle.stopDrag();
}

private function glowNearbySprites(event:Event):void
{
    var circleX:Number = circle.x;
    var circleY:Number = circle.y;
    for each(var tSprite:Sprite in sprites) {
        if (Math.abs(tSprite.x - circleX) < 30 && Math.abs(tSprite.y - circleY) < 30)
            tSprite.filters = theGlowFilterArray;
        else 
            tSprite.filters = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: probably add a variable for last position of circle.x / circle.y here, in case the mouse doesn't move

Answer (score 2):

I'd incorporate all the improvements that The_asMan suggested. Additionally, this line:

```
tSprite.filters = [new GlowFilter(0xFFFFFF)];
```

is probably really bad, since you're just creating the same GlowFilter over and over again, and creating new objects is always expensive (and you're doing this in a for loop every time a mouse_move fires!). Instead create it once when you create this class and assign it to a variable:

```
var whiteGlow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter(0xFFFFFF);

...

tSprite.filters = [whiteGlow];
```

If you're still having performance issues after this, consider only checking half (or even less) of the objects every time you call `glowNearbySprites` (set some type of flag that will let it know where to continue on the next call (first half of array or second half). You probably won't notice any difference visually, and you should be able to almost double performance.

Comment: After glancing at johns original code, I agree that the biggest performance hit is probably from the glow filter creation. +1

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that making calculations that are at least linear O(n) on every mouse change event is terribly inefficient.

One simple heuristic to bring down the amount of times that you make your calculations  is to save the distance to the closest sprite and only after mouse moved that distance would you recalculate the potential crash. This can be calculated in constant time O(1).

Notice that this works only when one sprite moves at a time.

Comment: One of the issues with this is that I want all nearby sprites to glow, not just the closest one.  I'm not sure if I fully understand what you mean though.

Comment: This is not an issue since the only thing you are doing is to reduce the amount of times you are comparing distances. I noticed that I didn't explain in a very clear way. I apologize for that. I am typing on an iPhone :)